Is this possible in Flutter (Android app)?
I was designing a music app, and for the bottom navigation bar, I wanted it to look like in the image. It is a linear gradient blur, but I don't know how to achieve this. Is this possible using Flutter?
Example of what I want to do
(I tried searching in Google, but I found nothing)

You can't just use a box shadow here because it does not blur the content behind it; it only spreads the blur of the container, so it will not be as vibrant as the design you have. What you need is a blur with a gradient mask.
But it's a bit tricky to implement that on a specific portion of the widget tree without copying it, so I have created soft_edge_blur to help with that exact issue:
https://github.com/Rahiche/soft_edge_blur
This is how you would use it to recreate the edge above:
Widget _buildBlurredEdge() {
  return SoftEdgeBlur(
    edges: [
      EdgeBlur(
        type: EdgeType.bottomEdge,
        size: 200,
        sigma: 30,
        tintColor: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor.withOpacity(0.8),
        controlPoints: [
          ControlPoint(
            position: 0.4,
            type: ControlPointType.visible,
          ),
          ControlPoint(
            position: 1.0,
            type: ControlPointType.transparent,
          ),
        ],
      )
    ],
    child: _buildContent(),
  );
}

it will look like this:


Try below code for blur background
body:Stack(
        children: [
          Container(
            // Background Gradient
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                colors: [Colors.red, Colors.red],
                begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                end: Alignment.bottomRight,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          BackdropFilter(
            filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 20.0, sigmaY: 20.0),
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.black
                  .withOpacity(0.5), // optional
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    bottomNavigationBar: Container(
        color: Colors.transparent, // Make the container transparent
        child: BottomNavigationBar(//your bottomNavigationBar code)
    )

